# PHP and html table, using tablesorter javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, sorting, html-table

I've setup tablesorter which works when using a basic html table. I'm now trying to call in data from a database which works but for some reason each set has its own heading which then stops me from being able to sort the data.

link to screenshot due to rep : http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f13xu5l6f

This is the code that is being used...

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>';

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($queryRetrieve, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{               
    echo ' <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">';
    echo ' <thead> ';
    echo ' <tr> ';
    echo '    <th>Fullname</th> ';
    echo '      <th>Age</th> ';
    echo '     <th>Email</th> ';
    echo '    <th>Contact no.</th> ';
    echo '   <th>Date Joined</th> ';
    echo ' </tr> ';
    echo ' </thead> ';

    echo ' <tbody> ';
    echo ' <tr> ';
    echo '     <td>'.$info["mFN"].'';
    echo '      &nbsp'.$info["mSN"].'';

    echo '    <td>'.$info["mAge"].'</td> ';
    echo '    <td>'.$info["mEmail"].'</td>';
    echo '    <td>'.$info["mPhone"].'</td> ';
    echo '    <td>'.$info["mDateJoined"].'</td> ';
    echo ' </tr> ';

    echo ' </tbody> ';
    echo ' </table> ';
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? quite new to coding and this is really bugging me now as I've tried quite a few methods and nothing seems to work when calling in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table header echo statements are also in the loop. Take out everything in your while loop except this part:

```
echo ' <tr> ';
echo '     <td>'.$info["mFN"].'';
echo '      &nbsp'.$info["mSN"].'';

echo '    <td>'.$info["mAge"].'</td> ';
echo '    <td>'.$info["mEmail"].'</td>';
echo '    <td>'.$info["mPhone"].'</td> ';
echo '    <td>'.$info["mDateJoined"].'</td> ';
echo ' </tr> ';
```

So your code after should look like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() 
      { 
          $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
      });
      </script>';


echo ' <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">';
echo ' <thead> ';
echo ' <tr> ';
echo '    <th>Fullname</th> ';
echo '      <th>Age</th> ';
echo '     <th>Email</th> ';
echo '    <th>Contact no.</th> ';
echo '   <th>Date Joined</th> ';
echo ' </tr> ';
echo ' </thead> ';
echo ' <tbody> ';

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($queryRetrieve, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{

    echo ' <tr> ';
    echo '     <td>'.$info["mFN"].'';
    echo '      &nbsp'.$info["mSN"].'';

    echo '    <td>'.$info["mAge"].'</td> ';
    echo '    <td>'.$info["mEmail"].'</td>';
    echo '    <td>'.$info["mPhone"].'</td> ';
    echo '    <td>'.$info["mDateJoined"].'</td> ';
    echo ' </tr> ';
}

echo ' </tbody> ';
echo ' </table> ';
```

Comment: No problem. Have fun coding!